# matlibplot graphing inside a button

Tags: matplotlib

I'm wondering why my matlibplot is currently graphing inside a button as shown below:

[image: Although kind of funny, quite annoying]

Code is shown below

```
from gui export Index
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(buttom-0.2)

pos_trim = plt.axes([0.20, 0.05, .1, 0.075])
b_trim = Button(pos_trim, 'Trim', hoverclor='0.25')

callback = Index(c)
b_trim.on_clicked(callback.autoTrim) # from gui.index

freqs = np.arange(2,20,3)
t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.05)
s = np.sin(2*np.pi*freqs[0]*t)

l, = plt.plot(t,s,lw=2)
plt.show()
```

Index class:

```
class Index:

  def __init__(self, chart):
    self.__chart = chart

  def autoTrim(self, event):
    print "Autotrim"
    #self.__chart.autoTrim()
    plt.draw()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your line where you plot the data to:

```
l, = ax.plot(t,s,lw=2)
```

That is, plot to the axes you created for the plot (`ax`).  Otherwise, you're plotting to the last axes you created, which in this case, is the button.